# Stylus dont push if already exsists (Grid Loop)

Tags: stylus

I'm trying to rewrite the following from SCSS to Stylus:

[link to original SCSS codepen grid loop](http://codepen.io/edmoore/pen/qFAGd)

```
// Total columns for layout
$total-columns: 6;
$col-widths: ();
@for $i from 1 through $total-columns {
    @for $j from 1 through $i {
        $w: ($j/$i);

        // If the width doesn't already exist
        @if not index($col-widths, $w) {
            .col-#{$j}-#{$i} {
                width: $w * 100%;
            }
            // Add the width to the array
            $col-widths: append($col-widths, $w, comma);
        }
    }
}
```

The part I'm stuck on however is

```
@if not index($col-widths, $w)
```

where I don't know how to check the col-widths array if the class w already exists and thereby not adding it again.

This is what I got so far but it's not working. What am I missing?

```
total-columns = 6
col-widths = ()

 for i in 1..total-columns 
   for j in 1..i 

     w = (j/i)

     if index in col-widths is not w
       .width{j}of{i} 
         lost-column: w
     else
       push(col-widths, w)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in` operator here (actually, your code is almost correct).

```
total-columns = 6
col-widths = ()

for i in 1..total-columns 
   for j in 1..i 

     w = (j/i)

     unless w in col-widths
       .width{j}of{i} 
         lost-column: w
       push(col-widths, w)
```